# Argument of type 'Promise<string | Buffer>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

```
  import fs from "fs";
  const fsp = fs.promises;

  /**
   * reads a file and returns its content in Buffer or string
   *
   * @param {string} path
   * @param {BufferEncoding} [encoding]
   * @returns {Promise<Buffer|string>}
   */
    const read = async (path, encoding) => {
        return await fsp.readFile(path, encoding);
    }

  const content = read("./test.txt","utf8");
  JSON.parse(content);
```

I have a read function in node.js that reads a file and returns either as **Buffer** if encoding is not specified or as **string** if encoding specified.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1&filetype=js#code/FAAhEsFsAcHsCcAuIBmBnV9aRAInbgNyggDGsAdmsutCALypoB00Wk4aApmsSQPQAqQSRCCQ8LgEMAJhimpwAGy4gpFGRK6IArvCoREGchURdTECiABCOlCi7wQCENXjgKAc1EiwYkAAC0FLwUjgA3m4engC%20IMGIABY%20gcGhEbb2jgCiFOQy0XEA2ub50QC6KQGSuvoY4QAK7JxcADyZDvAAPlFeAHwxPvyiZJTUWrIMamgAnnkgABQJiQA0IKWwBV4AlAx9IOEjflq1VlIA7lLgNGjQzJKyAGLKXEtSSWsbW57bxMeDJBM4xMZgsjAeMgWuGY-DM1GYiAAHohcCtcDpECgABy4X4kABSAGUAPIAOVYIW4CxB5kQvyAA)

In the code, the encoding is specified and it is clear **content** variable is a string type. But TS complains as

> Argument of type 'Promise<string | Buffer>' is not assignable to
> parameter of type 'string'.

How can I fix this issue and prevent TS from complaining?

P.S this is a JS file, not typescript. I try to use JSDocs with TS compiler in VSCode.

Comment: Use await to unwrap the value from the Promise. `const content = await read(...` to fix the first issue. Apart from that, you need more tricks if you want to adjust the return type depending on the params

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster thanks for the help, yeah I forgot to add await when I transferred the code to playground. Code works actually, it is just the warning. Should I just ignore it or create more conditionals or unnecessary specialized methods to suppress the warning?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] of the issue.  If you used `await` in your real code, then the real error did not say `'Promise<string | Buffer>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`, did it?  Presumably the `Promise` part is gone?  You're getting answers about `Promise` and if that's not the problem then it's just a distraction.

Comment: @jcalz the await version also produces same error.

Comment: The *same* error?  Are you sure?  Copy and paste the two next to each other and ensure that they both contain the word `Promise`.

Comment: @jcalz I can not edit the topic somehow. It gives error. I can not even share the updated Typescript Playground link in the comment because it is too long. https://codesandbox.io/s/sm9wsv?file=/index.ts You need to copy this code into TypeScript Playground to see the exact problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to do if you can't [edit] your question to be a [mre].  I'll check back later if you can figure it out.

Comment: Can I ask a new question with the same title and code and links updated? Is it allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a type check

```
  import fs from "fs";
  const fsp = fs.promises;

  /**
   * reads a file and returns its content in Buffer or string
   *
   * @param {string} path
   * @param {BufferEncoding} [encoding]
   * @returns {Promise<Buffer|string>}
   */
    const read = async (path, encoding) => {
        return await fsp.readFile(path, encoding);
    }

  const content = read("./test.txt","utf8").then((result) => {
    if(typeof result === "string") {
     return read
    }
    throw Error("Result is a Buffer") 
  })

  console.log(content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It should not throw error because I use this read function to pass Buffer data to response.write of HTTP module. When no encoding is passed, the function returns Buffer. The problem is TS can not see and differentiate when I passed an encoding parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

your `content` variable data type is `Promise`

you should use it like this

```js
read("./test.txt","utf8").then(content => {
     JSON.parse(content);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

you can add `.catch` for insurance so if you encounter any error, you won't going to have a runtime error